# How to take Object[] as return type in Spring DataJpa @Query methods?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch one row only by taking Object[] as return type in the @Query method of Repo interface. But while accessing the values it's showing 
   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

If i will take Object (not Object[])as return type in the @Query method and while calling it again i have to cast return type to Object[] to get the values. But I don't understand why i can't take Object[] as return type directly.

### Repo interface

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>{
    @Query("select e.empName,e.empSal from org.st.model.Employee e where e.empId= ?1")
 Object[] getData2(Integer eid);
}
```

### Runner class

```
   @Component
   public class ConsoleRunner implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repo;

    public void run(String...strings) throws Exception{
         Object[] obj = repo.getData2(106);//
                 System.out.println(obj[]);//No Exception no result but [Ljava.lang.Object;@68b366
         System.out.println(obj[1]);//AIOBException
      }
    }
```

I should get name(String) and sal(Double) value as result.

```
@Query("select e.empName,e.empSal from org.st.model.Employee e where e.empId= ?1 ") 
Object getData2(Integer eid); 

 Object[] obj = (Object[]) repo.getData2(106);  
System.out.println(obj[1]);
```

It's working fine.  cause i have taken **Object** as return type.      But i dont understand why **Object[]** as Return type is showing *AIOBE*.

Comment: Why not just get the employee `Optional<Employee> findById(Integer empId);` and in the runner class `Optional<Employee> emp = repo.findById(106); System.out.println(emp.isPresent()?"no employee":emp.get().getSal());`

Comment: yes but i want to know why Object[] is not working while Object Return type is working.

Answer (score 0):

Java array indexes starts with 0. If your Object[] obj has length 1, you need to retrieve it like this: obj[0]

Try this:

```
public void run(String...strings) throws Exception{
     Object[] obj = repo.getData2(106);
             System.out.println(obj[]);
     System.out.println(obj[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: His query says `@Query("select e.empName,e.empSal from org.st.model.Employee e where e.empId= ?1")`. So his array size must be 2, right? So obj[1] must be valid?

Comment: `@Query("select e.empName,e.empSal from org.st.model.Employee e where e.empId= ?1 ")`  `Object getData2(Integer eid);`  `Object[] obj = (Object[]) repo.getData2(106);`  `System.out.println(obj[1]);`  It's working fine.  cause i have taken Object as return type.      But i dont understand why Object[] as Return type is showing AIOBE.

Comment: This is not correct. This query returns a simple object array of one element, where the element is an Employee. Try to run this System.out.println(obj[0].getClass()) and you will see.

Comment: Yes but Object RT in @Query method is working after casting to Object[] while calling. Only the problem is Why Directly Object[] Return Type is not Working.

Comment: I believe your are misunderstanding how Spring Data JPA repositories are supposed to work. You have two options: either you query by ID using Optional<Employee> findById(Integer id); method already provided by Spring, or, if you really want only this projection you specified, create a custom projection using Views: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means you are trying to
>   access a array index that doesn't exist

```
Object[] results = repo.getData2(106);
for(Employee emp : results){    
   System.out.println(emp.getName() + " " + emp.getSal());
 }
```

Employee class must have getters.

But using the `List<Employee>` makes type safety,

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>{
    @Query("select e.empName,e.empSal from Employee e where e.empId= ?1")
 List<Employee> getData2(Integer eid);
}
```

and you can easily access

```
List<Employee> results = repo.getData2(106);
for(Employee emp : results){    
   System.out.println(emp.getName() + " " + emp.getSal());
 }
```

Comment: I want to fetch some of the properties only not all the properties of Employee class

Comment: Yes, you can fetch like this. No ptoblem

Comment: but whats the problem in RT Object[] while Object RT is working after casting.

Comment: Its not an issue, but this is a good practice for type safety

Comment: If you think this answer is helpful, please upvote and tick to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

Returning `Object[]` means that the query returns an array of records. Each record is itself an `Object[]`. Therefore access the first column of the first record you need to use `(Object[]) o[0])`.

You probably want to use use a [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) instead:

```
interface EmployeeView {
    String getEmpName();

    String getEmpSal();
}
```

---

```
@Query("select e.empName as empName, e.empSal as empSal from org.st.model.Employee e where e.empId= ?1")
EmployeeView getData2(Integer eid);
```

---

```
EmployeeView emp = repo.getData2(106);
```

Comment: Its showing null and null. I think in @Query method Projection don't work.

Comment: Add column alias in the jpa query to match the getters in the projection interface.

Comment: Yes then also m getting null in this case.